# Flutter : How can i make a notifcation that would pop-up every 5 minutes from a given time?

Tags: flutter, notifications

What package are suitable for it ?
I do know that the showDailyAtTime was removed from flutter_local_notifcations long time ago, is there an alternative to it ? and how do i use it ?
a simple code would be so helpful !

I tried to make it happens with multiple packages (cron, flutter_local_notifications, awesome_notifications) but all my efforts went up in a vain.